# A discrepancy between the usual interpretation of Bell's theorem and a full theory of quantum gravity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, string-theory, bells-inequality

**** This question has been modified following the discussion below. ****

Bell’s theorem says, in a nutshell, that “local hidden-variable theories (HVT) cannot exist” (since they contradict QM in Bell experiments, which are agreeing with QM). So only non-local HVT could reproduce all predictions of QM; “non-local” here means: involving superluminal signals/influences, i.e. non-Lorentz-invariant signals violating relativity theory (RT) (this is an explicit conclusion of Bell’s well-known article from 1964; some people nowadays understand “nonlocal” in a softer way, such as “violating Bell inequalities”, but for my question we need to use Bell’s original definition). That is why very few physicists believe in HVs, whether local or nonlocal.  Now, it seems to me that there is a significant gap between this standard interpretation of Bell’s theorem and the future construction of a full-blown theory of quantum gravity (F-QG). What I call a full theory of QG (F-QG) is one that can derive both QM and GR (general relativity) from more fundamental variables/properties/equations, so this would be a HVT allowing to explain QM and GR, just as electromagnetism can explain optics, magnetostatics etc as special cases, approximations, limits of a more fundamental theory. (String theory, ST, does not qualify as a F-QG, it seems, as follows from a discussion based on the original version of this question: ST is not a HVT, it assumes QM.)

Now, assuming a F-QG exists (see e.g. Nobel Laureate Gerard ‘t Hooft on this matter: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/504/1/012003), it seems to me that  the F-QG variables/properties/equations would NOT be nonlocal in Bell’s strong sense (i.e. involving non-Lorentz-invariant, superluminal signals) – they would allow to derive GR, after all. So such a F-QG would be a local HVT. My question: is this reasoning correct?

In sum, if I understand this correctly, there seems to be a discrepancy between the standard interpretation of Bell’s theorem and the research efforts of many theoretical physicists, who believe that a F-QG theory does exist: such a F-QG theory would be a local HVT.

Actually, there are one or two known escape-routes from Bell’s no-go verdict (Bell’s conclusion is based on one or two implicit assumptions, which are not trivial; see e.g. the work by ‘t Hooft, who does believe that the standard interpretation of Bell’s result is mistaken). Thanks in advance !

Comment: Relevant [Why string theory is quantum mechanics on seroids](https://motls.blogspot.com/2018/09/why-string-theory-is-quantum-mechanics.html).

Comment: @RamiroHum-Sah, I do not see how this site answers the question.

Comment: I write "relevant", not because the post answer your actual question, I shared it because it expresses the opinion, of a string theorist, that string theory is an "orthodox" usage of quantum mechanics in all known physics, including gravitational physics. The word "orthodox" in this context means, in particular, that the idea of hidden variables is incompatible with quantum gravity, because string theory is fully quantum.

Answer (score 2):

A hidden variable theory is a theory that isn't really quantum, but imitates quantum mechanics well enough to pass experimental tests.

String theory is really quantum. It doesn't derive quantum mechanics from more fundamental principles; it just assumes it. String theory predicts a violation of Bell's inequality for exactly the same reason as any other quantum theory.

I think it's plausible that research into quantum gravity could lead to some new insight into the nature of quantum mechanics, but I'm pretty sure it hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Thanks @benrg, that is interesting. But what I do not understand is: how can a theory that assumes QM and violates Bell’s inequality can also allow to derive RT? (One can read such things as “string theory has the potential to unify QM and RT”.) RT as a local and deterministic theory violates Bell’s inequality.

Answer (score 1):

The logic of perturbative string theory, goes in the following way.

Relativistic strings are the fundamental building block an a successful quantization of those strings actually exist (see any string theory textbook). What you learn from this is that quantum mechanics and special relativity are inputs in string theory. That shouldn't surprise no one, ordinary relativistic quantum mechanics does exactly the same.

What is amazing about string theory, is that there is no guarantee, that a framework that respects SR and QM can produce a consistent framework for the quantum mechanics of general relativity. In fact, there is no single example of such class of theories; except string theory.

Target spacetime in perturbative string theory can be literally tought as the moduli space of the string worldsheet scalars. The worldsheet CFT dictate the spacetime dynamics, and its quantum consistency force spacetime to obey Einstein's field equations. Much more is true, the quantum dynamics of spacetime (graviton scattering) is finite whitin string theory. Reference: [Why are there gravitons in string theory](https://motls.blogspot.com/2007/05/why-are-there-gravitons-in-string.html).

**To answer your actual question:** String theory is a purely quantum mechanical theory, hidden local or non-local variables are incompatible with the assumptions of string theory.

Comment: But if ST (string theory) is not a hidden-variable theory, how can it unify QM and RT? In the rest of physics, if a theory T unifies T1 and T2, all variables of T1 and T2 can be explained or reduced to quantities of T (e.g.  electrodynamics unifies, in this sense, optics and magnetostatics). If I understand you, ST does not unify (or has not the potential to unify) QM and GR in this sense. E.g. can spin be explained by string properties? And do the equations of GR follow from more fundamental string equations? No I think now. Bell's theorem allows to anticipate this impossibility (see above).

Comment: ST unify QM an SR in exactly the same way as ordinary relativistic quantum mechanics (a no hidden-variable theory) does. String theory derive GR from "more fundamental equations", Einstein's field equations arise as the requirement of the vanishing of the beta functions for the worldsheet scalar (an anomaly cancellation requirement). Does the spin of target space particles can be explained by string properties? yes, it follows from the BRST quantization and the GSO projection.

Comment: Allow me to ask you: Do you understand how ordinary relativistic quantum mechanics (RQM) unifies quantum mechanics and special relativity, without being a hidden variable theory? If your answer is yes, Do you understand that ST and RQM are exactly the same theory in the regime of validity of RQM? so, Why do you suspect that the argument that works in RQM is not satisfactory for string theory?

Comment: Yes, I think I understand your point, but I still think you use “unification” in a different sense (which is perhaps as interesting/important, the point is that it is a different kind of unification). As explained, in classical physics a theory T unifying T1 and T2 allows to show that T1 and T2 are approximations of T. Can one derive both the equations of QM and GR as approximations of ST? As far as I understood you, no.

Comment: The postulates of QM are inputs in string theory; string theory does not modify, nor derive in any way the usual rules of QM. The story with general relativity is different, GR is derived within string theory; As I said, GR is just string theory in certain limit (distances wide larger that the string scale). To me "unification" of QM and GR means a consistent (finite/renormalizable, anomaly free and UV complete) quantum mechanical description of graviton scattering that reproduces Einstein's general theory of relativity at large distances. That's what string theory actually is.

Comment: Thanks @Ramiro Hum-Sah, all this is extremely interesting. But from your explanations it sounds that ST is a full-blown theory of quantum gravity (QG). What you say seems in contradiction with what ‘t Hooft (Nobel) says on p. 13-14 in this article: 
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/504/1/012003. He says: "The problem of quantizing curved space-time, QG for short, is notoriously complex and far from understood. It may well be that a complete understanding of the quantum nature of our world will have to come together with the complete resolution of the QG problem”.